# Retrieve Value from Multiple Looped Textarea

Tags: php, for-loop, textarea

I've built a form for a short-answer quiz. Each question has multiple textboxes for answer (corresponding to instruction in the question i.e. list two components, three advantages, etc.). I've designed the form as such so that the answers can be evaluated independently against a set of answers. Each question can have many answer suggestions. Here is the 'answer' table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answer` (
`a_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`q_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`a_text` text NOT NULL,
`a_keyword` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

This is the code of the form:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['tf1_sid'])){
?>

<head>
<title>Dahlia | Formative Assessment</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="s_ass_result_new.php">
<h2>Short-answer Questions</h2>
<table width="590" border="0" cellpadding="2" align="center">
<?php
// db connect
include("dbconn.php");

// db query for questions
$sql_q  = "SELECT q_id, q_no, q_text, q_field FROM question";
$query_q = mysql_query($sql_q) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
// start loop for questions
//$rad = 1;
while($data_q = mysql_fetch_array($query_q, MYSQL_ASSOC)){     

$qfield = $data_q['q_field'];
$qno = $data_q['q_no'];

echo "<tr><td width='20' align='center' valign='top'><label><br /><input name='q_no' size='1' type='hidden' value=". $data_q['q_no'] .">". $data_q['q_no'] ."</label></td>";
echo "<td><br />". $data_q['q_text'] ." (<a href='s_help.php?s_id=". $_SESSION['tf1_sid'] ."&q_id=". $data_q['q_id'] ."' target='_blank'>Help</a>)</td>";

for($rad=1;$rad<=$qfield;$rad++){
echo "<tr><td></td><td><textarea name='answer_".$rad."' cols='55' rows='2' id='textarea1'></textarea></td></tr>";
echo "<script>document.getElementById('textarea1').focus()</script>";
//$rad++;
}
}
echo "<tr></tr><tr><td></td><td><input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Submit' onClick='return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")'></td></tr>";      
mysql_free_result($query_q);
include("dbconn.php");
?>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else
{
header("Location:s_login.php");
}
?>
```

The form is displaying fine but I'm having trouble retrieving values being submitted through the text area. Below is the code to retrieve those values:

```
<?php
// include db connection file
include("dbconn.php");
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{   
$id = $_SESSION['tf1_sid'];
$qno = $_POST['q_no'];
$ansspc = $_POST['q_field'];
?>

<head>
<title>Dahlia | Formative Assessment</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h2>Answer Review</h2>
<table width="590" border="0" cellpadding="2" align="center">
<?php

//db query to obtain i_id - to insert to RESULT table
$sql_i = "SELECT i_id FROM ins_stud WHERE s_id = '$id'";
$query_i = mysql_query($sql_i) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
$data_i = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_i);
$ins_id = $data_i['i_id'];

//$j = 1;
$arr_ind = 1;
$atext = array(1);
$ans = array(1);

//FOR LOOP TO RETRIEVE VALUES FROM TEXT AREA
for($i=1;$i<=$q_no;$i++){
for($k=1;$k<=$ansspc;$k++){
$repStr = str_replace("1", $k, "answer_1");
echo "Question ". $i .": Answer: ". $repStr;
$ans[] = $_POST[$repStr];
echo $ans;
}

$sql_check = "SELECT a_text FROM answer WHERE q_id='$i'";
$query_ch = mysql_query($sql_check) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
$data_ch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_ch);
$atext[] = $data_ch['q_ans'];       
//$j++;
}
...
```

It was working previously when I had the questions set with one text area each. What I intend to do is have each answer to be compared with each answer suggestion.

Example:

State two advantages of...

1. Two text area: ans1, ans2
2. Four suggested answers: soln1, soln2, soln3, soln4

So I'd compare ans1 with soln1, soln2, soln3, soln4 then the same goes for the ans2.

**Edited:**

```
//start loop for questions & answers
while($data_q = mysql_fetch_array($query_q, MYSQL_ASSOC)){     

//process returned data
foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $questionNumber => $answerList){
echo "question " . $questionNumber . ": \n";
foreach ($answerList as $key => $answer){
$ans[] = $answer;
echo "answer " . $key . ": " . $answer . "\n";
}//end foreach_in
}//end foreach_out

$jawapan = explode(" ", $ans[$arr_ind]);
$jwpn = trim($jwpn);

foreach($jwpn as $eval){
if (stripos($atext[$arr_ind], $eval) !== false){ //$atext: query for answer suggestions
//answer match with first suggestion
echo "<p align='justify'><img src='image/mark.png' border='0' width='20' height='20'> ". $ans[$arr_ind]. "</p>";
}//if
{else
//answer doesn't match with first suggestion; check next suggestion
for($m=1;$m<=$box;$m++){...}// $box = no. of text area in form
}//else

echo "<p align='justify'><label><b>SUGGESTED ANSWER:</b> <br><input name='answer_".$rad."' type='hidden' value=''>". $atext[$arr_ind] . "</label></p>";

$arr_ind++;
}//foreach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to use arrays in the naming of the textareas

Outputting the textarea (i left out all markup extras just to make it clear)
    while ($data_q = mysql_fetch_array($query_q, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

```
    $qfield = $data_q['q_field'];
    $qno = $data_q['q_no'];

    for ($rad = 1; $rad <= $qfield; $rad++) {
        echo "<textarea name='answer[" . $qno . "][" . $rad . "]' id='textarea_" . $qno . "_" . $rad . "'>";
    }
}
```

and processing the returned data

```
foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $questionNumber => $answerList) {
    echo "question " . $questionNumber . ": \n";
    foreach ($answerList as $key => $answer) {
        echo "answer " . $key . ": " . $answer . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks :) I've edited the original post where I added one line of code `$ans[] = $answer;` to compare the value in the text area with rows of data in database. Is the array also necessary in the for loop where I have to advance to the next rows? I'm having trouble coming up with a condition for the `else` clause.